# Cannot create table in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to create a table call USER_INFO in phpmyadmin, but I keep getting error #1050 - Table '`eataround`.`user_info`' already exists. In fact, I had previously dropped this table before recreating. Also I have tried to execute `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user_info;` in upper case or lower case, before create USER_INFO. But it is still not working.

Comment: Are you `DROP`ing it in the *correct* database?

Comment: Of course, even i click into the database (eataround), it do not show there are any table in this database.

Comment: seems like mysql crashed

Answer (score 0):

From the [MYSQL Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html):

> If you re-create a table that was dropped, it must have a definition
>   that conforms to the foreign key constraints referencing it. It must
>   have the right column names and types, and it must have indexes on the
>   referenced keys, as stated earlier. If these are not satisfied, MySQL
>   returns error number 1005 and refers to error 150 in the error
>   message.

Or it may be the case of a Schroedinger's table. So you may probably try this:

- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user_info
- REPAIR TABLE user_info
- If you have sufficient permissions, delete the data files (in /mysql/data/db_name)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to flush the table cache. For example:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tablename` ;
FLUSH TABLES `tablename` ; /* or exclude `tablename` to flush all tables */
CREATE TABLE `tablename` ...
```

also

from MySQL Log:

```
InnoDB: You can drop the orphaned table inside InnoDB by
InnoDB: creating an InnoDB table with the same name in another
InnoDB: database and copying the .frm file to the current database.
InnoDB: Then MySQL thinks the table exists, and DROP TABLE will
InnoDB: succeed.
```